# Autocorrect column value using List in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have eben trying to match state_name column with the List value , Its working well but when The Input Data becomes case sensitive

Input Data:

```
    state_name
0   Assan
1   Andhra Prade5h
2   M1zoram
3   Uttar Pr8desh
4   MIZORAM
```

**Script I have been using:**

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

lst = ['Assam','Andhra Pradesh', 'Mizoram', 'Uttar Pradesh'] #Correct Name List

def closest(s):
    highest = 0
    result = ''
    for i in lst:
        temp = SequenceMatcher(None, s, i).ratio() #Similarity Ratio
        if temp > highest:
            highest = temp
            result = i
    return result


df = pd.DataFrame(['Assan','Andhra Prade5h','M1zoram','Uttar Pr8desh'], columns = ["state_name"])

df['state_name'] = df['state_name'].apply(lambda x: closest(x))

#Output After
   

     state_name
    0   Assam
    1   Andhra Pradesh
    2   Mizoram
    3   Uttar Pradesh
    4   Assam
```

I am getting Wrong Values when Input value is Case sensitive For Eg. MIZORAM

Comment: what do you get after using "MIZORAM"?

Comment: What is the word `dictionary` doing in your question title?

Comment: @AvenDesta -  After using MIZORAM,  Mostly it gives Assam as the output which i have mentioned in question.

Comment: Is it a must to use `SequenceMatcher` to solve your problem, or you can consider some other library/method as well?

Comment: @ThePyGuy -  Library is working fine It just not giving correct output for the Uppercase input values.

Comment: Yes, I know. I asked it just out of curiosity..

Comment: I think the problem is with `SequenceMatcher`. "A" and "Z" might be closer to each other than "A" and "a"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert both values to lowercase:

```
SequenceMatcher(None, s.lower(), i.lower()).ratio()
```

Similar solution:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

lst = ['Assam','Andhra Pradesh', 'Mizoram', 'Uttar Pradesh'] #Correct Name List
arr = np.array(lst)

#convert list to lowercase 
lower = [x.lower() for x in lst]
def closest(s):
    #get index of maximal ratio
    idx = np.argmax([SequenceMatcher(None, s.lower(), i).ratio() for i in lower])
    #return value from list lst
    return arr[idx]


df = pd.DataFrame(['Assan','Andhra Prade5h','MIZORAM','Uttar Pr8desh'], 
                  columns = ["state_name"])

df['state_name'] = df['state_name'].apply(closest)

print (df)
       state_name
0           Assam
1  Andhra Pradesh
2         Mizoram
3   Uttar Pradesh
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you're using `SequenceMatcher`.

When SequenceMatcher compares two strings, it takes into consideration the case (-lower case or upper case), of the characters in the strings.

Example:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
temp1 = SequenceMatcher(None, "Hello", "hello").ratio()
temp2 = SequenceMatcher(None, "Hello", "HELLO").ratio()
temp3 = SequenceMatcher(None, "Hello", "Jelme").ratio()

print(temp1)  # 0.8
print(temp2)  # 0.2
print(temp3)  # 0.4
```

The above shows, with your code, "Jelme" is closer to "Hello" than "HELLO".
One way to deal with this is changing the string to lowercase with `str.lower()`.